# SQL join query, want to get the latest record of joining table (or null if it doesn't match)

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables

User:

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Jane |
| 3 | Jim |

login:

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-29 |
| 3 | 2021-02-27 |
| 1 | 2021-03-11 |
| 3 | 2021-04-18 |

I want to get the result like:

| name | date |
| --- | --- |
| John | 2021-03-11 |
| Jane | null |
| Jim | 2021-04-18 |

How shall I write the SQL query?

I tried quite a few join but never got the 2nd record (Jane/Null) out from the query. Need some help here, thanks a ton in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `left join` and `group by`:

```
select u.id, u.name, max(l.date)
from user u left join
     login l
     on l.id = u.id
group by u.id, u.name;
```

Note:  This includes the `id` as well.  If `name` is known to be unique that is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

complimenting @gordons answer another option is to use a subquery like follows

```
SELECT user.name, login.last_login
FROM user
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, max(date) AS last_login FROM logins group by id) AS login
ON login.id = user.id
```